# Get 10 unique random questions from mongodb for a quiz game

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a quiz database in mongodb with 10000 questions. I would like to retrieve 10 random questions for a user such that they are non repeating till all the options are exhausted and then I have the ability to reset or loop back. I am well aware of aggregate() and sample() that handle the random part but they don't offer unique rows. What would be the right way to handle this? Is it possible using mongodb/mongoose or should I switch to mysql?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to request more documents from your collection, `$group` the result to ensure the given results are unique and then limiting the result count to 10 :

```
Model.aggregate([{
    $sample: { size: 100 }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        document: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}, {
    $limit: 10
}], function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(res);
})
```

If you don't have 10 documents in the end, you would have to query again or increase the amount of data in the `$sample` stage